# How can I make a C program, run it in 2 terminals and change a shared variable simultaneously?

Tags: c

I need to make a C program that is able to run simultaneously in two different terminals and modify a variable. If the variable is modified in one running program, for example to 4, then the variable should change to 4 in the other running program. I am guessing that this should be done with multiple processes but i can't figure out how to code it. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Google "inter-process communication" also read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] .  As written this question is not answerable -- OS?  "terminal"?  access to shared storage, memory?

Comment: I agree with Dave. The question is a very interesting one, but in it's present state it does not fit here. That's why I'm flagging it for removal.

Comment: This is far too broad to answer. There are many ways to do what you want but we can't tell which is best in your case. Off the top of my head: use a database or use a shared memory segment.

Comment: Simplest way to do it is to store the value in a file and read it from the file whenever it's needed. Of course you need to solve the problems if both instances writes at the same time and such.

Comment: @klutt it depends on definition of a 'terminal'. Might need sockets :-)

Comment: @Serge True enough. As already stated, the question is far to broad.

Comment: With terminal I refer to the command line window

Answer (score 0):

### A fun solution (Only on Linux)

Using process signals ! On a Linux system you have some process signals which are called User Signals.

Here is what you need to acomplish that :

1. A function to translate an **integrer to a binary sequence**.
2. A function to translate a **binary sequence to an integrer**.
3. A function to send a binary sequence **with process signals** (huh).
4. A function to read a binary sequence **with process signals**.
5. Some basic knowledge like **ping-pong**

### Some explanations

Considering :

- 85 (Random number) : The number used to tell the other process the number 
                      changed. The other process will wait for the new 
                      integrer binary sequence.

Here is the process :

1. Give to the process B **the pid of the process A** (This is done by 
   **user-input**)
2. process B : Detected integrer changed
3. process B : Convert 85 to a **binary sequence** -> "1010101"
4. Process B : Send it to the process A

Lets explain that using a sample of pseudo-code :

```
/* Lets stay simple, we will consider you are storing your
   binary sequence in a char[20] for example */

   int main(void) {
     sendToProcess(PID, 12);
   }

   void sendBinarySequence(sequence, PID) {
     loop through sequence {
        /* The best way here is to always send 4 bytes, increment a value so 
           the process A don't have to tell you when the sending is done 
        */
        if (bit == 1)
          kill(PID, SIGUSR1);
        else if (but == 0)
          kill(PID, SIGUSR2); 
       /* Wait for the signal of the process A, we are using ping-pong 
       */
     }
   }

   void sendToProcess(PID, NB_TO_SEND) {
     // Send 85 to the process
     char binary[20];

     convertNbToBinary(&binary[0], 85); /* This is the first integrer we 
     will send, then the process A will know we will send integrer. */
     sendBinarySequence(binary, PID);
   }
```

5. For both process (you want them to communicate) we will handle signal using
   [signal()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html), knowing you can handle received signals. Lets build a 
   function which handle SIG_USR1 and SIG_USR2 signals, **when the process
   receive a SIG_URS1, add 1 to our binary sequence and 0 when we receive 
   SIG_USR2**. Yayyy, now the process A have the sequence you've send.
6. Just convert your binary sequence to an integrer and replace his value.

## An easy solution (Linux/Windows)

Use a file... When process A change write it to file.txt, at X frequency the process B check the file, if its different, change the value of his integrer.